# ASCII string as dtype for numpy array of strings in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, python-3.x

NumPy's `string` dtype seems to correspond to Python's `str` and thus to change between Python 2.x and 3.x:

In Python 2.7:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.dtype((np.str_, 1)).itemsize
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: np.dtype((np.unicode_, 1)).itemsize
Out[3]: 4
```

In Python 3.3:

```
In [2]: np.dtype((np.str_, 1)).itemsize
Out[2]: 4
```

The version of NumPy is 1.7.0 in both cases.

I'm writing some code that I want to work on both Python versions, and I want an array of ASCII strings (4x memory overhead is not acceptable). So the questions are:

- How do I define a dtype for an ASCII string of certain length (with 1 byte per char) in Python 3?
- How do I do it in a way that also works in Python 2?
- Bonus question: Can I limit the alphabet even further, e.g. to `ascii_uppercase`, and save a bit or two per char?

Something that I see as the potential answer are character arrays for the first question (i.e. have an array of character arrays instead of an array of strings). Seems like I can specify the item size when constructing one:

```
chararray(shape, itemsize=1, unicode=False, buffer=None, offset=0,
          strides=None, order=None)
```

Update: nah, the `itemsize` is actually the number of characters. But there's still `unicode=False`.

Is that the way to go?

Will it answer the last question, too?

And how do I actually use it as `dtype`?

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer to your very last question is a big NO. AFAIK, and  I did look into it some time back, there is no way of packing data of less than 8 bits into less than 1 byte. Definitely not for 6 or 7 bit types, but unless you handle it yourself, you can't have 2 four bit values in a single 8 bit container either. Even `bool` arrays take a full 8 bits for every `True`/`False` value they store.

Comment: @Jaime Wow, okay. I want 1 byte then :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the 'S' [typestr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface):

```
>>> np.array(['Hello', 'World'], dtype='S')
array([b'Hello', b'World'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Also in 2.6/2.7 `str` is aliased to `bytes` (or `np.bytes_`):

```
>>> np.dtype((bytes, 1)) # 2.7
dtype('|S1')
>>> np.dtype((bytes, 1)) # 3.2
dtype('|S1')
```

And `b''` literals are supported:

```
>>> np.array([b'Hello', b'World']) # 2.7
array(['Hello', 'World'], 
      dtype='|S5')
>>> np.array([b'Hello', b'World']) # 3.2
array([b'Hello', b'World'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```